# File read performance test yields interesting results. Possible explanations?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, file-io, windows-7

I'm stress-testing my system to determine just how much punishment the filesystem can take. One test involves repeated reads on a single small (thus presumably heavily cached) file to determine overhead.

The following python 3.6.0 script generates two lists of results:

```
import random, string, time

stri = bytes(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(100000)), 'latin-1')

inf = open('bench.txt', 'w+b')
inf.write(stri)

for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = b''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(t*10):
        inf.seek(0)
        readl += inf.read(200)
    print(t/10.0, time.perf_counter()-start)

print()

for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = b''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(3000):
        inf.seek(0)
        readl += inf.read(t)
    print(t/10.0, time.perf_counter()-start)

inf.close()
```

When plotted i get the following graph:

[image: Results graph]

I find these results very weird. The second test (blue in the picture, mutable read lenght parameter) starts off linearly increasing which is expected, then after a point it decides to climb much more quickly. Even more surprisingly, the first test (pink, mutable repetitions count and fixed read length) also shows the wild departure which is interesting because the size of the read function remains fixed there. It's also very irregular which is head-scratching at best. My system was idle when running the tests.

What plausible reason could there be that causes such a major performance degradation after a certain number of repetitions?

**EDIT:**

The fact that `readl` is a byte array apparently is a major performance hog. Switching it to a string drastically improves everything. Yet even when working with strings, calling the read and seek functions is a minor factor by comparison. Here are more test variants of test 1 (mutable repetitions). Test 2 is left out because its results turn out to be entirely explained by the byte array performance difference alone:

```
import random, string, time

strs = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(100000))
strb = bytes(strs, 'latin-1')

inf = open('bench.txt', 'w+b')
inf.write(strb)

#bytes and read
for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = b''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(t*10):
        inf.seek(0)
        readl += inf.read(200)
    print(t/10.0, '%f' % (time.perf_counter()-start))
print()

#bytes no read
for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = b''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(t*10):
        readl += strb[0:200]
    print(t/10.0, '%f' % (time.perf_counter()-start))
print()

#string and read
for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = ''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(t*10):
        inf.seek(0)
        readl += inf.read(200).decode('latin-1')
    print(t/10.0, '%f' % (time.perf_counter()-start))
print()

#string no read
for t in range(0,700,5):
    readl = ''
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(t*10):
        readl += strs[0:200]
    print(t/10.0, '%f' % (time.perf_counter()-start))
print()

inf.close()
```

[image: Results graph]

Comment: Could you regenerate the results using `time.clock` instead of `time.time`? It might very well be that Windows schedules less CPU time for your process when you do more I/O operations in order to respect other processes as well (i.e. it let's other processes do their I/O in between the ones of your process). Running your code on Ubuntu 16.04 yields results which are very different: case 2 is linear and case 1 is somewhat parabolic. Also some remarks: 1. Your axes have no labels. 2. Both loops run over the same `range` however on the plot the green one seems to be truncated (why?).

Comment: @a_guest, use `time.process_time()` in Python 3.3+. On Windows, `time.clock()` is wall time.

Comment: I found `perf_counter()` to be the most accurate. I tried `process_time()` which gives the same matching results but at a much lower resolution. Also updated graph.

Comment: If you regenerate graphs, are they differently wired or are they identical looking? Differently wired may point to other system load, take a look at those articles about stable benchmarks: https://haypo.github.io/journey-to-stable-benchmark-system.html (there's three articles in the serie).

Comment: Ok I found that the most important factor is apparently `readl` being a byte array. If i use `readl = ''` and `readl += inf.read(200).decode('latin-1')` the results are vastly smoother (and much faster). Will append this to my question.

Comment: @JulienPalard Yes they do vary, except when they don't. I can manage to have different patterns and irregularities only if i change open applications, reboot the system or disable the antivirus. If nothing changes however, the patterns remain virtually the same when rerunning the tests.

Comment: Repeatedly appending to `readl` eventually gets expensive. At a certain threshold a `realloc` of the memory block will have to allocate a new block and copy. At that point the curve switches from linear to nonlinear. For example, for `t == 530`, it appends 200 bytes 5300 times. By iteration 5243 it's up to a megabyte. At this point the heap probably always allocates a new memory block and copies. Then for subsequent values of `t` up to 700, the total time taken by the inner loop is growing nonlinearly in `t`.